# Files and folders in Cygwin look the same

Tags: cygwin, customization, appearance

Does anyone know how to make files and folders look different in Cygwin?
Perhaps by bolding the folders or some other equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found my solution in the ~/.bashrc file.

For anyone who comes to this post in the future, all you have to do is uncomment the following line: `alias ls='ls -hF --color=tty'  # classify files in colour`

Comment: Btw, when you'll need the vanilla ls, you'll have to call it like that `\ls`